# Drupal Drop down menu wont work

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Hi I created a custom menu in D7, but I have a problem, I didn't get the dropdown works,

Here's my code

```
<nav id="myMainNav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <?php if ($main_menu): ?>
              <div id="navigation"><div class="section">
                <?php print theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('nav', 'navbar-nav', 'navbar-right')), 'heading' => t(''))); ?>                
              </div></div> 
            <?php endif; ?>
        </nav>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If it's custom then you also need some CSS, maybe JS, dependng on your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [`menu_tree_all_data`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7) in conjunction with [`menu_tree_output`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_output/7) and make sure parent menu items has `Show as expanded` set to true.

```
 <div id="navigation"><div class="section">
 <?php 
      $menu_tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
      $menu_output = menu_tree_output($menu_tree);
      print drupal_render($menu_output);
 ?>                
 </div></div>
```